# Should I render all of my HUD views to a single SurfaceView?

Tags: android, html-canvas, gui

I'm using a `SurfaceView` and canvas to implement a game HUD, title screens etc., by overlaying standard Android view widgets over my `SurfaceView`. This works reasonably well and maintains an acceptable frame-rate, but it is a simple game with little happening on or off screen.

I have handlers flinging messages around and `runOnUiThreads` everywhere. Quite cumbersome. Can I draw all my views to the one `SurfaceView`, controlled by the main game thread? Is there an advantage to this?

Answer (score -1):

actually you could draw all that staff on your canvas but you need to handle that ui things from strach, like getting user touch points and detecting whether user touched a button or not